# second particle hair system made both disappear from render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-groups, hair

I got the beard working fine with the vertex group. I added a second vertex group for the eyebrows, added a second particle system and now both have disappeared from the render

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch back into object mode before you render. If you stay in particle edit, it won't render. One of Blender's quirks.  Does that seem crazy? You tell me.